# Chart legend with row style cuts off

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Chart in ASP.NET and C#. Whenever I have the chart legend style as row, it cuts off extra labels and displays three dots "..."

Is there anyway to fix this or make the legend width larger without changing the chart width?

Here is my code for the chart:

```
<asp:chart id="crtMain" runat="server" Height="700" Width="700">
    <titles>
        <asp:Title ShadowOffset="3" Name="Default" />
    </titles>

    <legends>
        <asp:Legend Alignment="Center" Docking="Bottom" IsTextAutoFit="False" Name="Default" LegendStyle="Row" />
    </legends>

    <series>
        <asp:Series Name="Default" />
    </series>

    <chartareas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="crtArea" BorderWidth="0" />
    </chartareas>
</asp:chart>
```

And the code behind:

```
crtMain.Series["Default"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;

crtMain.Series["Default"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

crtMain.ChartAreas["crtArea"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "c";
crtMain.Series["Default"].LabelFormat = "c";

crtMain.ChartAreas["crtArea"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 15F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
crtMain.ChartAreas["crtArea"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 15F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
crtMain.Series["Default"].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 15F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
crtMain.Legends["Default"].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 14F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);

 crtMain.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
```

And picture of the issue:
[image: Chart Issue]

Which is coming from the chart here:

[image: Chart]

Any ideas at all?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE:
So I figured out how to do this.

I simply put in the code behind:

```
crtMain.Legends["Default"].IsTextAutoFit = true;
crtMain.Legends["Default"].MaximumAutoSize = 100;
```

This expanded all the text so I could see every label.

Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

[image: Chart Fixed]